# How call a function in C, from an project in assembler language in CodeWarrior?

Tags: function, codewarrior

The project is assembler only, for MC9S08 micro.

The problem is BME280 sensor, I need insert (if possible)
a function in C with compensation formule (ARDUINO)

The project is working and no want to create a new in C.

Comment: I honestly don't think it is possible

Comment: AGREE. then I have to do a routine in assembler with the compensation.

Comment: // Returns temperature in DegC, double precision. Output value of “51.23” equals 51.23 DegC.
        // t_fine carries fine temperature as global value
BME280_S32_t t_fine;
double BME280_compensate_T_double(BME280_S32_t adc_T)
{
double var1, var2, T;
var1 = (((double)adc_T)/16384.0 – ((double)dig_T1)/1024.0) * ((double)dig_T2);
var2 = ((((double)adc_T)/131072.0 – ((double)dig_T1)/8192.0) *
(((double)adc_T)/131072.0 – ((double) dig_T1)/8192.0)) * ((double)dig_T3);
t_fine = (BME280_S32_t)(var1 + var2);
T = (var1 + var2) / 5120.0;
return T;
}